# Load xml and xslt from embedded resource in Saxon 9.4he

Tags: c#, xml, xslt, uri, saxon

I am using Saxon 9.4 home edition ([Saxon-HE 9.4 .NET](http://saxon.sourceforge.net/#F9.4HE)) to get support for XSLT 2.0 and XPath 2.0, and XQuery 1.0 in .NET. My code crashes when I load files without an URI.

1. Is it possible to load xml/xsl documents without an URI related to the document loaded?
2. If not, is there any way to define URI for elements embedded in dll-files?

Any other solutions will also be appreciated, my only term is that the files must be loaded from within the dll-file.

My code works perfectly as long as i load xml/xsl from file:

```
const string sourcePath = @"C:\test\TestInvoiceWithError.xml";
const string xsltpath = @"C:\test\UBL-T10-BiiRules.xsl";
```

When i try to load from embedded resource the code throws an exception stating *'No base URI supplied'*:

```
Stream sourceStream = GetEmbeddedResource("TestProject1.testfiles.TestInvoice.xml");
Stream xsltStream = GetEmbeddedResource("TestProject1.testfiles.UBL-T10-BiiRules.xsl");
```

I have also created Uri's for resources with relative path which throws the exception *'This operation is not supported for a relative URI.'*:

```
Uri sourceUri = new Uri("/TestProject1;component/testfiles/TestInvoice.xml",     UriKind.Relative);
Uri xsltUri = new Uri("/TestProject1;component/testfiles/UBL-T10-BiiRules.xsl.xml", UriKind.Relative);
```

Here is my code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting;
using Saxon.Api;


namespace TestProject1
{
    [TestClass]
    public class XsltTest
    {
        [TestMethod]
        public void SaxonTest()
        {
            Stream sourceStream = GetEmbeddedResource("TestProject1.testfiles.TestInvoice.xml");
            Stream xsltStream = GetEmbeddedResource("TestProject1.testfiles.UBL-T10-BiiRules.xsl");

            Uri sourceUri = new Uri("/TestProject1;component/testfiles/TestInvoice.xml", UriKind.Relative);
            Uri xsltUri = new Uri("/TestProject1;component/testfiles/UBL-T10-BiiRules.xsl.xml", UriKind.Relative);

            const string sourcePath = @"C:\test\TestInvoiceWithError.xml";
            const string xsltpath = @"C:\test\UBL-T10-BiiRules.xsl";

            Processor processor = new Processor();
            XdmNode input = processor.NewDocumentBuilder().Build(new Uri(sourcePath));

            XsltTransformer transformer = processor.NewXsltCompiler().Compile(new Uri(xsltpath)).Load();

            transformer.InitialContextNode = input;

            Serializer serializer = new Serializer();
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            TextWriter writer = new StringWriter(sb);
            serializer.SetOutputWriter(writer);

            transformer.Run(serializer);

            XmlDocument xmlDocOut = new XmlDocument();
            xmlDocOut.LoadXml(sb.ToString());
            XmlNodeList failedAsserts = xmlDocOut.SelectNodes("/svrl:schematron-output/svrl:failed-assert",XmlInvoiceNamespaceManager());

            if (failedAsserts == null)
                return;

            foreach (XmlNode failedAssert in failedAsserts)
            {
                if (failedAssert.Attributes == null)
                    continue;

                XmlAttribute typeOfError = failedAssert.Attributes["flag"];

                if (typeOfError.Value.Equals("warning"))
                {/*Log something*/}
                else if (typeOfError.Value.Equals("fatal"))
                {/*Log something*/}
            }
        }

        private XmlNamespaceManager XmlInvoiceNamespaceManager()
        {
            IDictionary<string, string> list = new Dictionary<string, string>
                                                   {
                                                       {"xml", "http://www.w3.org/XML/1998/namespace"},
                                                       {"xsi", "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"},
                                                       {"xsd", "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"},
                                                       {"udt","urn:un:unece:uncefact:data:specification:UnqualifiedDataTypesSchemaModule:2"},
                                                       {"qdt","urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:QualifiedDatatypes-2"},
                                                       {"ext","urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:CommonExtensionComponents-2"},
                                                       {"ccts", "urn:un:unece:uncefact:documentation:2"},
                                                       {"cbc","urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:CommonBasicComponents-2"},
                                                       {"cac","urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:CommonAggregateComponents-2"},
                                                       {"inv", "urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:Invoice-2"},
                                                       {"svrl", "http://purl.oclc.org/dsdl/svrl"}
                                                   };

            XmlNameTable xmlNameTable = new NameTable();

            XmlNamespaceManager xmlInvoiceNamespaceManager = new XmlNamespaceManager(xmlNameTable);

            foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> ns in list)
            {
                xmlInvoiceNamespaceManager.AddNamespace(ns.Key, ns.Value);
            }
            return xmlInvoiceNamespaceManager;
        }

        protected static Stream GetEmbeddedResource(string path)
        {
            Assembly asm = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
            Stream stream = asm.GetManifestResourceStream(path);
            return stream;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you can load from a stream with Saxon but you need to set a base URI first that would allow to load any references resources (like a DTD in an XML document or like included or imported stylesheet modules). If you are sure you don't have that then simply try e.g.

```
DocumentBuilder db = processor.NewDocumentBuilder();
db.BaseUri = new Uri("file:///C:/");

XdmNode input = db.Build(xsltStream);
```

Obviously if you need to resolve relative URIs in the XSLT that are also to be loaded as embedded resource more work is needed: you need to set up the `XmlResolver` to a class that supports loading the resource from an embedded resource, together with a scheme of URIs in the XSLT to indicate to the resolver that you need to load from a resource. I don't think the .NET framework provides such a kind of XmlResolver and the Uri class does not support a custom schema for that either.

Comment: Thank you! Did not realize that BaseUri was referring to reference resources rather than the actual document.

Comment: We try to write the code so that having no base URI only causes problems when the base URI is actually needed for something. But it's surprising how many things it does get used for, so it's always best to set one, and best to make it a valid absolute URI. If you can't think of any sensible thing to set it to, use something recognizable in error messages, e.g. file:/invented.base.uri/

Comment: It seems to be enough to use new Uri("file://") for me. Or has someone a problem with that?

Comment: Do not forget to set the position of the stream to 0.

Answer (score 1):

Recently,I encountered this problem. And this is my solution.

```
private void test() {
        Stream xsltStream = GetEmbeddedResource("TestSaxon.Resources.test.xsl");

        Processor processor = new Processor();

        DocumentBuilder db = processor.NewDocumentBuilder();
        XmlDocument xmlDocument = new XmlDocument();
        xmlDocument.Load(xsltStream);

        XdmNode xdmNode = db.Build(xmlDocument);

        XsltTransformer transformer = processor.NewXsltCompiler().Compile(xdmNode).Load();
        var path = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory;
        var input = new FileInfo(path + @"\input.xml");
        var output = new FileInfo(path + @"\result.xml");
        var destination = new DomDestination();
        using (var inputStream = input.OpenRead())
        {
            transformer.SetInputStream(inputStream, new Uri(input.DirectoryName));
            transformer.Run(destination);
        }
        destination.XmlDocument.Save(output.FullName);
    }

    protected static Stream GetEmbeddedResource(string path)
    {
        Assembly asm = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
        Stream stream = asm.GetManifestResourceStream(path);
        return stream;
    }
```